# Effect of lambda declaration on function stack size

Tags: c++, lambda, stack

I have an inline function that uses a map to return a value. This map can be initialized during the first function call. I use a lambda for that:

```
inline float GetFloat(int inInt)
{
    static std::map<int, float> const Map = []() -> std::map<int, float>
    {
        std::map<int, float> Result;
        // Example initialization:
        Result.emplace(0, 1.5f);
        Result.emplace(1, 2.5f);
        Result.emplace(2, 72.0f);
        //etc?

        return Result;
    }();

    auto Float = Map.find(inInt);
    if (Float != Map.end()) return Float->second;
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Now my question is: Does the lambda itself affect the amount of stack size this function takes (ignoring the effect it obviously has on the size of the map)?

Comment: The only way to know is to check the assembly.  A good compiler will inline it and no variable for the lambda will be created at all.

Comment: Are you asking whether there will be any additional stack use relative to using a normal function rather than a lambda? Because if the lambda is inlined, there may be additional stack use for the contents of the lambda body. The same is true with a normal function. I don't know what you mean with "*(ignoring the effect it obviously has on the size of the map)*". The `std::map<int, float>` is static and so will not take up any stack at all. And its size is also always the same.

Comment: The first time the function scope enters, the lambda gets constructed and invoked to initialize the statically scoped object. This may use some stack space, unless the compiler optimizes out the NVRO and inlines the lambda call. Afterwards, none.

Comment: @walnut I didn't know static variables didn't take up stack. Guess that makes sense, thanks. Yes that's my question - does the lambda body itself (likely) take up stack use.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld You answered "*Yes*", but then followed it with the opposite of what I asked. The lambda body does take up space if it is inlined because of the local variables declared in the lambda body and inlined function calls inside the lambda. But that would be true for a free function as well. So discussing that is pretty pointless. If the lambda is not inlined, there might (but doesn't need to) be a single one byte stack object for the lambda. But all of this discussion is only based on reasonable assumptions about compiler optimization anyway.

Comment: Definitive answer are only possible by looking at the assembly generated by your compiler.